# group adjacent with constraints?

Tags: grouping, xslt-2.0

I'm having an issue while using group-adjacent. Below a simplified XML snippet :

```
<Paras>
<Para tag="Bind">
    <Content>some standalone Bind data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="L3">
    <Content>some header data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="BStep.n=1">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="Bind">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="BStep.n+">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="BStep.n+">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="Bind">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="Bind">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="L1">
    <Content>some header</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="BBox.n=1">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="BBox.n+">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="Bind">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="BBox.n+">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="Bind">
    <Content>some data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="L2">
    <Content>some header</Content>
</Para>
</Paras>
```

What I like to get after final transformation is something as below :

```
<Paras>
<Para tag="Bind">
<Content>some standalone Bind data</Content>
</Para>
<Para tag="L3">
<Content>some header data</Content>
</Para>     
<StepGroup>
        <Steps>
            <Para tag="BStep.n=1">some data</Para>
            <Para tag="Bind">some data</Para>
        </Steps>
        <Steps>
            <Para tag="BStep.n+">some data</Para>
        </Steps>
        <Steps>
            <Para tag="BStep.n+">some data</Para>
            <Para tag="Bind">some data</Para>
            <Para tag="Bind">some data</Para>
        </Steps>
    </StepGroup>
    <Para tag="L1">
        <Content>some header</Content>
    </Para>
    <BoxGroup>
        <Steps>
            <Para tag="BBox.n=1">some data</Para>
            <Para tag="BBox.n+">some data</Para>
            <Para tag="Bind">some data</Para>
        </Steps>
        <Steps>
            <Para tag="BBox.n+">some data</Para>
            <Para tag="Bind">some data</Para>
        </Steps>
    </BoxGroup>
    <Para tag="L2">
        <Content>some header</Content>
    </Para>
</Paras>
```

Or, to make it a bit textual : All 'bstep' type of tags and 'bind' tags that are adjacent to each other should be grouped in a StepGroup Element, and also all 'bblock' type of tags that are adjacent, including Bind tags, should be grouped in a 'BoxGroup' element.

I used following xslt (only partly shown) :

```
<!-- Some data above this left out ... -->
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="@tag='BStep.boxnmb.n=1'  or @tag='BStep.boxnmb.n+' or @tag='Bind' or @tag='BStep.nobox' ">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
<StepGroup>
<!-- do some stuff with group / not included now -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
</StepGroup>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="@tag='BBox.n=1'  or @tag='BBox.n+' or @tag='Bind'">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
<BoxGroup>
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
</BoxGroup>
</xsl:when>
```

This works partly, but as I have 'Bind' tags in both types of adjacent groups I need to be able to modify the group-adjacent keys so that for the 'StepGroup' only 'Binds' are included where the element has a 'Step type' tag, and for the 'BoxGroup' only 'Binds' where the previous element has a 'Box type' tag. I've tried some things but all resulting in nice error messages, so I hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your requirements, here is some partial solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Paras">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Para" group-adjacent="matches(@tag, 'BStep|Bind')">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <StepGroup>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="Para[matches(@tag, 'BStep')]">
                <Step>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </Step>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
            </StepGroup>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="matches(@tag, 'BBox|Bind')">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <BoxGroup>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </BoxGroup>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
Here is an adaption of the first stylesheet that should do the first level of grouping as you asked for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Paras">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Para" 
        group-adjacent="matches(@tag, 'BStep|Bind') 
                         and (self::Para[matches(@tag, 'BStep')] 
                              or preceding-sibling::*[not(matches(@tag, 'Bind'))][1][self::Para[matches(@tag, 'BStep')]])">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <StepGroup>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="Para[matches(@tag, 'BStep')]">
                <Step>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </Step>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
            </StepGroup>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="matches(@tag, 'BBox|Bind')">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <BoxGroup>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </BoxGroup>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that with Saxon 9 to your input document I get

```
<Paras>
   <StepGroup>
      <Step>
         <Para tag="BStep.n=1">
            <Content>some data</Content>
         </Para>
         <Para tag="Bind">
            <Content>some data</Content>
         </Para>
      </Step>
      <Step>
         <Para tag="BStep.n+">
            <Content>some data</Content>
         </Para>
      </Step>
      <Step>
         <Para tag="BStep.n+">
            <Content>some data</Content>
         </Para>
         <Para tag="Bind">
            <Content>some data</Content>
         </Para>
         <Para tag="Bind">
            <Content>some data</Content>
         </Para>
      </Step>
   </StepGroup>
   <Para tag="L1">
      <Content>some header</Content>
   </Para>
   <BoxGroup>
      <Para tag="BBox.n=1">
         <Content>some data</Content>
      </Para>
      <Para tag="BBox.n+">
         <Content>some data</Content>
      </Para>
      <Para tag="Bind">
         <Content>some data</Content>
      </Para>
      <Para tag="BBox.n+">
         <Content>some data</Content>
      </Para>
      <Para tag="Bind">
         <Content>some data</Content>
      </Para>
   </BoxGroup>
   <Para tag="L2">
      <Content>some header</Content>
   </Para>
</Paras>
```

I realize this is not yet a final solution but I have so far not understood what defines the grouping inside of a BoxGroup. Maybe you can explain that in more detail or you can fix that part yourself.

Comment: Thanks already Martin. The script you provided is already a bit more condensed then what I use, but it's not really fixing the problem as such. The first section (looking at stepgroup) works fine indeed, but for the second part (the boxgroup), the bind tag is already converted to a 'stepgroup', while it should actually be part of the 'boxgroup'. So 'Bind' tags followed or preceded by a 'Step' tag, belong together in a Step group, while Bind tags followed or preceded by a box tag also belong together. But since all Bind tags are already processed with the first <for-each- ...> it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Martin ! This surely helps me to achieve what I need.